# What's causing my phone to freeze?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, system-error, system-freeze

I Have a Samsung Galaxy S2.
I had it for around 2 weeks, when it first turned itself off and wouldn't turn back on again. The keyboard would glitch and stop working. and apps like Facebook, or Google Play, Internet etc would freeze then the error  `'Application' Is not responding` send error report etc.

I've just got it back from repairs, and the applications are still stopping responding, it hasn't crashed yet though. Any ideas what could be making it do this considering they've completely wiped the phone and screened it etc?

Comment: Was it second hand? It could be a hardware issue...

Comment: An idea would be connecting the device via USB to your PC, and run `adb logcat` (or using a logcat app to do this -- ADB variant is more practicable, as I will show). Now when something stops responding, immediately look at the log output and capture what's displayed. When re-deirecting `adb logcat` to a file, and stopping the process just after the "freeze" happens, indications should be at the end of the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

I removed Facebook and it seemed to have helped my phone run better. Before I was getting flooded with invites from the same person and my phone was constantly freezing.